# How to animate this responsive toggle menu?

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, toggle

I've found this very good looking responsive menu (resize browser window to see it in function):

http://themetaq.com/demos/responsive-toggle-menu/

I managed to implement it in my website, but I was wondering how could I add a smooth "slide down" animation to the menu, instead of just appearing like it does now.

Everything about its behaviour should be here (plugins.js)

```
/* MOBILE COLLAPSE MENU */
(function($) {
  $.fn.collapsable = function(options) {
// iterate and reformat each matched element
return this.each(function() {
  // cache this:
  var obj = $(this);
  var tree = obj.next('.navigation');
  obj.click(function(){
    if( obj.is(':visible') ){ tree.toggle();}
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() <= 570 ){tree.attr('style','');};
  });
});
};
})(jQuery);
```

and here (script.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slide-trigger').collapsable();
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just be able to change

```
obj.click(function(){
     if( obj.is(':visible') ){ tree.toggle();}
});
```

to

```
obj.click(function(){
    if( obj.is(':visible') ){ tree.slideToggle();}
});
```

But I haven't been able to test this - could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: It works PERFECTLY. I feel kinda dumb seeing how easy the solution was. Thank you so much!

Comment: Woo hoo!  No worries - it is only easy if you knew about slideToggle()!